# any documentation about Orchard 1.1 project

Tags: orchardcms

Since Orchard project is so complex, I wanna know if there is a documentation for this or not?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for Orchard can be found at: http://docs.orchardproject.net/

Comment: I mean documentation for web developers not for those who want to use it.

Comment: There is some developer documentation, not a lot but I guess it depends what you're trying to do: http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Developer-FAQ.ashx

Comment: No it's not. Most of the documentation has been updated for 1.1 before 1.1 was even available.
Is there any particular topic you are interested in seeing?
http://orchardproject.net/docs/

Comment: @Bertrand Le Roy I thought it was only 1.0 at the moment as some pages still say "This topic has been updated for the Orchard 1.0 release." but you're right, there are others where it says they're at 1.1.